# Unterminated JSX contents for displaying React a react Property

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a property through react components and display the text property of that element I get know JSX sytax errors but I get Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents.When attempting to display the text from the property but instead it's blank as if its not reading the property

```
Components.js

import React from "react"

function Components(props) {
    return (<div>
                <h1 style={style}>COMPONENT.js</h1>
                <div>{props.text}</div>
            </div>)

}

export default Components
```

```
App.js

import React from 'react';
import Component from "./component"

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      The Big World
      <Component text="PROPERTY TEXT"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
Index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Expecting to see the property text to be pass through the Component property and displayed on the page

Answer (score 0):

All looks clear. Try to add semicolon an the end of return statement:

```
function Components(props) {
    return (
             <div>
                <h1 style={style}>COMPONENT.js</h1>
                <div>{props.text}</div>
             </div>
           );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran all this in a codesandbox and other than `style` not being defined it all renders and runs fine. I also don't think it is an error with a typo in your posted code (the file is actually `components.js` and not `component.js`), because that shouldn't transpile at all since it can't find that file.

[image: Edit keen-kilby-2o22m]